# Update the whole django model in one request

Tags: django

I am using Django and have a `User` model and a `UserProfile` model. `User` and `UserProfile` has one to one relationship.

The `UserProfile` model has some fields like "gender", "birth_date" etc. I need to add another field called "profession_info", where a user can add multiple profession-related properties: "profession", "designation" and "description". The user can add multiple "profession_info".

How can I accomplish this task? And what is the easiest and most efficient way to update the user's profile?

Comment: you are working with django rest API ??

Comment: Yes. I am beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add other `manytomany` field in model like below

```
class ProfessionInfo(models.Model):
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    profession_info = models.ManyToManyField(ProfessionInfo)
```

after adding these fields you can create a `serializer` in your Django REST API and get professional data with your user data like below

```
class ProfessionInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfessionInfo
        fields = ['profession', 'designation', 'description']

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # use profession info from another serializer with many true
    profession_info = ProfessionInfoSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['gender', 'birth_date', 'profession_info']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # remove profession_info before saving userProfile object.
        profession_info_data = validated_data.pop('profession_info')
        profession_info = []
        for info_data in profession_info_data:
            info, _ = ProfessionInfo.objects.get_or_create(**info_data)
            profession_info.append(info)
        instance.profession_info.set(profession_info)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

reference for `set` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation with code. I have one question. Is it best practice to declare that field as ManyToMany because one userprofile has multiple professions and one professioninfo has only one userinfo. So onetomany makes much more sense. I know there is not OneToMany in Django. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: That is possible in this case also. One use can have multiple professions. As you can see in code that we are looping over profession info and inserting that into profession model, so one user can have multiple profession.
There is other way of doing with JSON or Array of JSON but manytomany field is suitable as we can expand it further whenever required by adding more fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Learned new technique for updating the model